# High CPU temperature when using GNOME

Tags: gnome, kde, cpu, overheating, temperature

I have ASUS Extensa 4220 laptop.
If I install Kubuntu (any KDE-based), then the CPU temperature looks normal for a long time (now it is 74 degree Celsius).
 But when I install GNOME-based distros, then the temperature after some minutes of work rises to 90 degrees Celsius, and my laptop shuts down to prevent damages. 
Why is there such a big difference with CPU temperature between KDE and GNOME? 
Also when I used Windows 8, the CPU temperatures there were normal (higher than on KDE, and not as high as on GNOME. Just for information.)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: intel graphic driver https://01.org/linuxgraphics/